# Where do ASP.NET "website prejects" store default reference/assembly settings for VB/C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

MY understanding is like this, for the "website type" of projects:

for VB, the **default** setting for the namespaces and the **default** setting for references are both stored in C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\V4.0.30319\Config\Web.config.

but C# does not seem to use this global web.config file to store its **default** namespaces and references settings. One evidence is that you see a lot of "using ..." statements at the top of all C# files whereas you don't see many "imports ..." statements at the top of all VB files. So C# stores the namespace settings in individual .cs files, but where does C# store the reference settings then? Or the C# compiler knows all the reference without having to store it somewhere?

It seems to me VB is way more naturally compatible with the whole .NET setup. (I'm quite new to .NET). Thanks.

Comment: @user: Web Site "projects" are not projects. Everything else you do in Visual Studio has a project. Only web site "projects" do not. The polite way to say it is that they are targeted at developers who are unfamiliar with sophisticated development environments. The harsh way to put it is that they were designed for script-kiddies who are too stupid to understand projects and other modern software development practices.

Comment: @user: Do not be surprised, when you have a problem with a "web site", that you get answers from people who don't understand your problem, or if you have problems which only apply to web sites (like, web sites don't have a build step, you include the sources on the site, and they just build when they feel they need to build, on the fly).

Answer (score 1):

Search for WebForm.zip in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE